# #dask Local abort before MPI_INIT completed completed successfully

Tags: mpi, dask

I run command as follows.

```
mpirun --hostfile /home/user/share/hostlist.txt -np 4 /home/user/share/mpi-dask/venv/bin/dask-mpi --scheduler-file ~/dask-scheduler.json
```

I got result as follows.

```
*** An error occurred in MPI_Init_thread  
*** on a NULL communicator  
*** MPI_ERRORS_ARE_FATAL (processes in this communicator will now abort,  
***    and potentially your MPI job)  
[rpi40000:14497] Local abort
```

before MPI_INIT completed completed successfully, but am not able to aggregate error messages, and not able to guarantee that all other processes were killed!

```
2022-06-23 06:40:12,321 - distributed.nanny - INFO - Worker process 14497 exited with status 1  
2022-06-23 06:40:12,324 - distributed.nanny - WARNING - Restarting worker  
^C[rpi40000:14416] PMIX ERROR: UNREACHABLE in file ../../../src/server/pmix_server.c at line 2795
[rpi40000:14416] 8 more processes have sent help message help-orte-runtime.txt /   orte_init:startup:internal-failure  
[rpi40000:14416] Set MCA parameter "orte_base_help_aggregate" to 0 to see all help / error messages  
[rpi40000:14416] 5 more processes have sent help message help-orte-runtime / orte_init:startup:internal-failure  
[rpi40000:14416] 5 more processes have sent help message help-mpi-runtime.txt / mpi_init:startup:internal-failure
```

Comment: try running a MPI hello world program, and then a `mpi4py` hello world program. A possible root cause is `mpi4py` was not built with the same MPI library than `mpirun`. FWIW, the error message suggests `mpi4py` was built with Open MPI.

Comment: ```mpirun --hostfile /home/user/share/hostlist.txt -np 16 /home/user/share/test/hello.o```
is ok

rpi40000: 1 of 16  
rpi40000: 2 of 16  
rpi40000: 3 of 16  
rpi40000: 0 of 16  
rpi40003: 13 of 16  
rpi40001: 7 of 16  
rpi40003: 14 of 16  
rpi40001: 4 of 16  
rpi40002: 9 of 16  
rpi40003: 15 of 16  
rpi40001: 5 of 16  
rpi40002: 10 of 16  
rpi40003: 12 of 16  
rpi40001: 6 of 16  
rpi40002: 11 of 16  
rpi40002: 8 of 16

Comment: And of cource, hello.py is ok
```mpirun --hostfile /home/user/share/hostlist.txt --np 16 python3``` /home/user/share/test/hello.py  
Hello, World! I am process 5 of 16 on rpi40001
Hello, World! I am process 6 of 16 on rpi40001

Comment: the path to dask-mpi suggests a virtual environment is used. can you run `hello.py` in the same virtual environment?

Comment: if dask-mpi not virtual environment, I got same error.

Comment: you ran with `-np 4` but the logs mention 8 MPI tasks(!) are you sure the logs match the command?